# Function of ておく in 伝えておきます

Tags: grammar, set-phrases, aspect

ておく basically means to do something in advance/preparation, and 伝えておきます seems to be a common saying for "I will tell somebody", e.g.

> 素晴らしい披露宴だったと彼に伝えておきます。

I do not understand how does ておく here work, for I see nothing about "doing in advance" in this sentence.

Comment: I'm not sure, but 伝えておきます might be a humble expression, because 伝えておいてください conversely sounds a little bossy  or as if complaining.

Answer (score 5):

I think of ておく as putting an action into place so that it する's (does its convenient effect) later. Additionally, you get it out of your mind. You proactively do it and get it out of your way.

Maybe there is some effect her saying will do to her husband. Something like making him take a certain decision, putting him into a good mood so that she can X,Y,Z...

[Here](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/teoku/) it is descibed as "to do something for future convenience".

Comment: Agree.  For OP, some auxiliary verbs such as ～ておく or ～てみる can be used pretty liberally without a huge change in meaning, or *fully* incorporating the exact definition.  In this case, the "future convenience" meaning is both nuanced and implied.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, I'm guessing (needs more context!) this this would come across as saying "I will tell him it was a wonderful reception" while implying "...so you don't have to tell him" or "...so he doesn't have to ask". (Depending on the context, it could imply a million other things. Ex: "...to make him jealous for you" or "...to hide the fact that you didn't actually have a reception")

I haven't found this particular wording, but I'd say that ておく can simply imply that you are doing something for a positive purpose. It's similar to てしまう, but with a positive connotation.

Another example:

> 濃厚接触者になったため、在宅勤務にしておきます。

I was exposed, so I will work from home (purpose: "to play it safe")

> 濃厚接触者になったため、在宅勤務にしてしまいまう。

I was exposed, so I will work from home (implies that the speaker has a reason not to want to work from home)

The first example could be explained with @0149234's "for future convenience" definition, but often times you'd use ておく subconsciously, without fully realizing what those conveniences are--hence "for some positive purpose"

Answer (score 1):

If you said 伝えます it would most likely be understood to mean you will tell him right away. By saying 伝えておきます it becomes clear you tell him at some point in time before it's too late, that is, in the near future.